# fluentd: read if a new file is created

Tags: fluentd

Can fluentd read from the file if a new file is created?

I have a directory `/path/to/somewhere/`. If a new file is created in the directory, I would like to read data from the file with fluentd.

I can not find the input plugin that do this in [this page](http://docs.fluentd.org/v0.12/articles/input-plugin-overview).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `path /path/to/somewhere/*` in in_tail plugin.

Then fluentd is able to detect new files in the directory.

[See here](https://docs.fluentd.org/v0.12/articles/in_tail#path-(required))